# Dynamic queue for implementing Breadth-First algorithm efficiently

Tags: java, performance, queue, breadth-first-search

I am in the midst of constructing a Breadth-First graph searching algorithm, for searching the London Underground.

I have the algorithm figured out but as you may well know, the algorithm requires a Queue ADS in order to track all of the edges that need searching (in the correct order).

I have been reading about efficiency issues to do with managing the queue and a large or very large number of queued items (edges).

Can anyone please tell me how to implement a queue based around the Java ArrayList, that can track head and tail and that manages the memory effectively while it's growing?

Any tips/pointers much appreciated!!

Comment: The first thing I would ask is do you actually have a problem - is it making you wait? The second is if it's making you wait have you sampled to see what it's spending most time doing. That FIFO might be a problem, but a priori, probably not. Just as a ballpark guess, you should be able to process 1 node every microsecond, so I wouldn't think speed would be a problem.

Comment: I would rather use some kind of specialised queue because it would be beter than sorting my queue all the time. Although it's not essential to do it, I would just like to find out more about queues and how they can be done.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need to sort, but anyway, @Kim's answer looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is closely related to this topic: [Breadth-First search in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489204/breadth-first-search-in-java)

Don't use ArrayList unless you have a *really* good reason. Java already comes with a great set of queue implementations -- see the [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface for details.

In your case, it might suffice to pick [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) as your queue implementation.  See also http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/BFSDFS.aspx for an easy to follow example of a breadth first search implementation that uses LinkedList as a queue.

Comment: Ah ha I see you can just use LinkedList like that. Well that's not too tricky. I'm sure some will research about queue efficiency techniques!

Comment: You might also want to check out PriorityQueue if you need your elements to be sorted.  And @Keith's suggestion of using a Set for fast graph coloring. I think the breadth first sample code also uses a set to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind you're going to want a fast test to see whether your object is already in the queue or not.  Neither `ArrayList` nor `Queue` provide this functionality (their `contains` check is `O(n)`).  If you can modify the objects you are dealing with by adding an extra field, then it is easy.  If not, you'll want to maintain some sort of fast `Set` (a `HashSet`, probably) to keep track of which objects are in the queue.

Comment: I see that's really interesting. I can easily introduce a HashSet of objects previously traversed and make sure they're not added to the queue (their edges).

Comment: This would be via the `HashSet``contains()` method? Is this faster becuase it uses a `hashCode()` lookup?

Comment: Yes, HashSet.contains is fast.  Read up on hash tables if you want to understand why they are fast.  It's more than just using hashcode().

Comment: It's ok I have used Dictionary types plenty before. Just checking it wasn't faster because it had less Edges in it.